# Submit filter form on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to make something a bit like this:

[image]

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/19/

```
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function (e) {
    var cache = $(this).next('ul');
    $('#filter ul:visible').not(cache).hide();
    cache.toggle();
});
```

I'm trying to make it degradable so without javascript they can submit the form to adjust the results, but with javascript they can just click the text of the desired result.

**Question A**

How can I make it so by them clicking the text alone, with javascript enabled, it not only selects the radio button but also submit the form.

**Question B**

Is my code the right approach to achieve this desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the radio buttons with submit buttons.

```
<input type="submit" name="status" value="Status 1">
```

Comment: Oh really? I never thought of that. I don't really understand how this works with forms, do I need one form for each filter (date, status etc) or one form which includes all filters, or instead no form at all?

Comment: That depends largely on how you implement the backend. Having one form per filter (and tracking the previously set values through hidden inputs in each) would probably be simplest.

Comment: Aside from there being no `<form>`, that looks OK.

Comment: It never allows you to apply more than one filter though, is that right? As in I couldn't filter by status AND date at the same time?

Comment: @Jimmy — See the second sentence of my first comment: "and tracking the previously set values through hidden inputs in each"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. So, if I may, in order to pass multiple parameters to the url we will need all submit buttons to belong to the same form, and you're saying to use something like a select field for each filter which has all the option values in, and this is kept up to date when the user uses a submit button with their selected values. Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: No. You have one form per set of options. You then put the currently selected options from other forms in as hidden inputs. e.g. `<form id="date"> <input type="hidden" name="sort_order" value="relevance"> <input type="submit" name="date" value="Any time"> <input type="submit" name="date" value="Last 24 hours"> etc`

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/30/) with submit buttons that are hidden if javascript is enabled.

```
<div>
    <form action="/echo/html/">
        <ul id="filter">
            <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any status ▾</a>
                <ul class="opt">
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="status" />Status 1</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="status" />Status 2</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any date ▾</a>

                <ul class="opt">
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="date" />Date 1</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="date" />Date 2</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="results">
    Filtered results go here
</div>
<script>
    $("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
    $('#filter > li > a').on("click", function (e) {
        var cache = $(this).next('ul');
        $('#filter ul:visible').not(cache).hide();
        cache.toggle();
        $('#filter li input[type=submit]').hide();
    });
    $('#filter input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $('#results').html('filtering...');
        $.post($form.attr('action'),$form.serialize(),function(response) {
            if ( response ) {
               $('#results').html(response);
            } else {
               $('#results').html('no results found');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think google uses `<a>` tag instead `<input>` and (but i'm not sure) catches the click and makes a ajax call to update only the result (without any form)... like: http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/25/

HTML, change `<input>` in `<a>`:

```
<a href="search.action?status=status1">Status 1</a>
```

JS

```
$('ul.opt a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".opt").find("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $.get($(this).attr("href"),function(res){
        //do something with response
    });
});
```

On `<a>` click the JS simply perform `search.action` (or other search service) with `sortDate=status1` like parameter via AJAX, for sort the result.

You can concat the sorting parameters `status=status1&date=date1` for multiple sorting.

I don't know if there are any ways to perform the submit without using javascript (and without reload all page).

Comment: I like your example. Cleaner than radio buttons and with an automatic fallback.

Comment: thx... really there are a lot of ways to follow for do what the OP want, but maybe he should treat his way, according to the service (API) he the UI he needs...